# How do I allocate more of my physical memory?

Tags: c#, memory

I am getting this error when loading large files into memory. What I don't understand is that my memory (as monitored by Task Manager still says only 7G used on a machine that has 32G). Is this memory exception referring to a constrained part of this memory? And, if so, how do I allocate more.  The code producing the error is below.

```
System.OutOfMemoryException occurred
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
  InnerException:
```

Active (x86) and 64bit Windows 7

Code:

```
       public void LoadAllBinaries(string aKey)
        {
            if (msDatas != null)
                return;

            msDatas = new SortedDictionary<string, byte[]>();

            var dataFiles = File.ReadAllLines(G.ConfigDir + @"\dates_out.txt");
            foreach (var df in dataFiles)
            {
                try
                {
                    string fn = G.DataDir + "\\n" + aKey + df + ".dft";
                    byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(fn);
                    msDatas.Add(fn,ba);
                    ba = null;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OpenSLoadAllBinariestreams ERROR: " + e.Message);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: How is the program compiled? "x86" or "Any CPU" or...? Which OS version? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: You're most likely failing to find a large enough contiguous block of memory to read into.

Comment: Do you have to real ALL files into memory? could you no process it incrementally? one file at a time..

Comment: Active (x86) and 64bit Windows 7

Comment: @LatheesanKanes I am CHOOSING to read them all in so that later, my processing of the data is NOT I/O dependent

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: 32-bit processes are limited to 2GB of process memory - change the configuration to be x86_46.

Comment: To make use of >4GB of memory, use "Any CPU" or "x64" as a configuration.

Comment: @ManInMoon THat is with all respect a little naive. The IO you spend reading the files is the same - just now you are doing that at program start. Unless you process them multiple times you save exactly zero IO and a decent buffer and async procesing would be as efficient. Ever heard of memory mapped files? That would solve the whole load issue quite nicely.

Comment: -1 This code is just broken. Just because you "set ba to null" doesn't free up the memory. Its still in your dictionary. Loading all your files into memory before you do your processing is a really bad idea. Assuming your files are larger than 85k you will have memory fragmentation. Finally, this process is going to be I/O bound no matter what you do (unless you slow it down with something even slower, like a monkey).

Comment: @TomTom I AM processing multiple times!

Comment: @ManInMoon even so. Memory mapped files would be the way to go IFF you are actually feeling pain in your performance (with MMF you get OS level in-memory caching). This is an XY problem if I have ever seen one.

Comment: I agree. Loading into memory like this is reckless and wastefull. MMF are the way to go. THe OS can do caching as well or better as you do.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That worked! If you want to put that as an answer - I will accept it. Many thanks

Comment: @ManInMoon it will only for a short period. Look up Large Object Heap and Memory Fragmentation. You are going to bring down your server.

Answer (score 0):

You've either got a memory leak somewhere, or a handle leak. Both will give you the Out Of Memory error.

You can see if you've got a handle leak by opening TaskManager, go to View, Select Columns..., and turn on Handles. Start your process and let it run through a few iterations. Jot down the numbers you get. Then come back in a few hours and compare the numbers. If the handles numbers are considerably higher, you're not Disposing an object than you should be.

Also ensure that you dispose of your objects as well. You can also try use `System.GC.Collect` for garbage collection. Hope this helps.

Comment: It only takes a few seconds to get to error! I believe the only object I create is ba - and I set that to null each time

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure but your exception stacktrace says

```
at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
```

To me it looks like the below line of code is the culprit and it's throwing OOM exception cause most most probably the size of `dates_out.txt` is high enough.

```
File.ReadAllLines(G.ConfigDir + @"\dates_out.txt")
```

What's the size of the file `dates_out.txt` you are reading? if it's in size of GB then try reading it line by line rather reading the entire file at once (as suggested by others over comment).

**EDIT:**

If you want to see current memory consumption of a program’s object, then you can get it using `GC.GetTotalMemory` method. You can also use `windbg.exe tool` or `Microsoft’s CLR Profiler`

```
long memoryUsed = GC.GetTotalMemory (true);
```

Comment: @ManInMoon, big enough file size. even if you try to open it in notepad you will feel the pinch. BTW, what's your physical memory size (RAM)?

Comment: 32G - 16M should not be an issue. WHat I don't understand is why I do not see Task Manager show memory as used up...

Comment: @ManInMoon If you read the comments above, you'll see that a single x86 process can't use more than 4GB in-process memory, so you won't see much more than that being used.

Comment: @ManInMoon its not A 16M file. Its many 16MB files. Additionally, you need to assign a 16MB continuous block of memory for this file. Additionally, this will be on the LOH, which means its pinned, and hence will very quickly use up continuous memory.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio go to Project Properties and Build screen.  Check that where Any CPU is selected that the platform target checkbox for Prefer 32 bit is not checked.

You can also explicitly select x64 there.

This resolved the same error for me.